# Need library to open 3d video c++

Tags: c++, video, 3d

i'd be interested in a c++ (if any) library to handle and elaborate 3d video files. I need to process the NifTI and Analyze format.

Thanks

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: i used the search form provided by stackoverflow, google search and asking to itk insight user mailing list. I'm already using openCV and it works fine with 2D video elaboration but can't handle 3d ones

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`opencv`](http://opencv.org/) for video processing. It is a very good library for processing video and you can also edit video. It provides a lot of inbuilt functions to process video.

To see an example [click](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.in/2011/09/capturing-images-videos.html) here.